# MYSQL :GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP ERROR

Tags: mysql

I have a table with id, desc, quantity. I used `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP` to get the subTotal in the result.

<kbd>[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1b5cd/2)</kbd>

In the result i want to know how to make the "description" column blank for the row created by roll up

In my actual scenario i have other columns also, but rolled up only on one column. So other columns should be empty.

Comment: Edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `''` rather than `NULL`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(id,'TOTAL'),
       (case when id is null then '' else description end) as description,
       sum(qty) AS SUM
FROM item
group by id WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: excellent, but how can i fix the description column for id = 2 , and id =3 ? the value of the description column is repeated for both id =2 and 3